# Supertrace of holonomy of commutator

Tags: gauge-theory, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory, brst, wilson-loop

On page 47 of [Surface operators in four-dimensional topological gauge
theory and Langlands duality](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0385) by Kapustin et al., the following expression is given 
\begin{equation}
\delta\mathcal{N}=d(\omega_\bar{i}\eta^{\bar{i}}+T)+[\mathcal{N},\omega_\bar{i}\eta^{\bar{i}}+T].
\end{equation}
It is then claimed that the supertrace of the holonomy of this expression vanishes, i.e., that
\begin{equation}
STr\textrm{ e}^{\oint\delta\mathcal{N}}=0.
\end{equation}
My question is, how does on show this?

Using Stoke's theorem, one can show that 
\begin{equation}
STr\textrm{ e}^{\oint\delta\mathcal{N}}=STr\textrm{ e}^{\oint [\mathcal{N},\omega_\bar{i}\eta^{\bar{i}}+T]}.
\end{equation}
However, I have no idea as to how this expression should vanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the same page of the paper, $\mathcal{N}$ is defined as a connection on a bundle $\sigma^* E$. The claim that its BRST variation is
$$\delta_{\text{BRST}} \,\mathcal{N} = \mathrm{d} \alpha + [\mathcal{N},\alpha],~~~ (\alpha = \omega \eta + T),$$
means that $\delta_\text{BRST} \mathcal{N}$ is just a gauge transformation of $\mathcal{N}$, $\delta_\alpha \mathcal{N} = \mathrm{d}_\mathcal{N}\, \alpha$, with $\mathrm{d}_\mathcal{N} = \mathrm{d} + [\mathcal{N}, \cdot]$ the gauge-covariant derivative. The trace of the holonomy around a curve $C$ is just a Wilson loop,
$$W_C(\mathcal{N}) = \mathrm{str} \,\mathrm{P}\, e^{ \oint_C \mathcal{N}},$$
which is of course a gauge invariant operator. It is therefore also BRST invariant.